# Brother DCP-J572DW does not scan after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 20.04, scanner, brother

In version 18.04 SimpleScan worked fine, as did the printing function. After the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 my Brother DCP-J572DW device did not print nor did it scan.

When I first launched Document scanner, then turned on the printer/scanner, the reply is that an extra driver program is required.
I did find the download on the Brother page, downloaded it and installed via driver-installer. The printer does now print again, so it made a difference.

At first, after quiting Documentscanner, with the scanner on, I launched Documentscanner again and Lo and Behold!, it does recognise the device Brother DCP-J572DW and tells me it is ready to scan, but as soon as I try to scan, the message appears "cannot connect to scanner" (in Dutch, but that is not the problem).

Next step: set preferences and try to scan again; the device seems to start, but only shows a window, no further action or the well-known scanner noise. So I hit the "stop" button.

Start a new scan delivers the message "Contacting scanner" (in Dutch again, which is fine). The wheel in the stop-button starts turning, but no action whatsoever. So I stopped it once more.
Then tried to quit Documentscanner, which does not react att all. After some minutes it signals: Program does not react. Force quit? Yes, of course, and indeed it does disappear from the screen.

Then tried XSane. After launch it says "searching for scanner". After a while it returns with "could not find device 'brother4:bus2;dev1', wrong argument.

The upgrade apparently mixed up some settings in a directory that I, as a simple end-user, never had to deal with (that is the great advantage of Ubuntu!). As my experience with UNIX dates from 30 years ago, I recognise the commandline interface, but only remember the commands cd.. and ls -l. Can someone instruct me how to correct this scanner thing?

Nico

Comment: My solution was to remove the printer from Ubuntu and reinstall using the script from the Brother support site. Now printing and scanning both work correctly

Comment: Hello Eagle_Mike, Thanks for your answer. You mean the Driver Install Tool on the Brother site (version 2.2.2.1)?

Comment: Correct, the Driver tool from the Brother web site.

Comment: Mike, followed your advice, but still just printing, no scanner. Still searching, Brother support is activated as well, but did not find the right trick yet.

Answer (score 0):

Either connect to the device by wireless and use [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) or read [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=329760).